# Is there any Apache cordova API to convert HTML, CSS & JS files zip to an app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I've seen many websites which ask users for JSON of their blog and within few seconds they create and give downloading link for apk file, I know they are using cordova but is there any api like www.cordova.com/webapp-to-android?zip=[URL] where I can send my zip file and in return get apk file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [phonegap build](https://build.phonegap.com/) where you have to upload zip file with your html, css and js file with one config.xml file.

Config.xml file contain name of your app, package name, app icon detail, splashscreen, plugins detail etc configuration.